AKS on Azure Local - can it be managed offline?
Generally, AKS Arc clusters and AKS on Azure Local can be managed with the Azure portal. Or with az aksarc.
For example az aksarc create creates a cluster.
This is quite convenient, when there is access to the Azure portal. However, when the connection goes down, is there a possiblity to manage clusters, for example, scale node pools with az aksarc nodepool scale? And can a connection with kubectl be made when there is no connection to Entra ID?
There is also a Disconnected operations feature for Azure local, which should provide a local control plane and therefore enable disconnected operations.
But does it work to some extent with "plain" Azure local?

while AKS on Azure Local supports offline operations for isolated environments, the extent of functionality varies based on pre-setup and the specific configuration of the local environment.

Yes, AKS on Azure Local can be managed offline to some extent using the Disconnected Operations feature, which provides a local control plane for managing clusters without relying on Azure's cloud. This enables essential tasks like scaling node pools and accessing clusters with kubectl, provided local identity solutions (such as Active Directory) and offline management tools are pre-configured.
However, certain advanced functionalities, such as using az aksarc nodepool scale, may require connectivity to Azure services like Entra ID. For "plain" Azure Local, offline capabilities depend heavily on pre-downloaded updates, configuring local repositories, and ensuring local identity provider integration.
Also found few similar links for reference-

Can AKS be used fully on-premise and without internet connection?
Azure Arc - without full internet.

